# Reqular expressions in Android with input that contains []{}"

Tags: android, regex

I am trying to extract the X and Y component using a regular expression from the following data:

```
{"SearchResults":[{"PageCount":"0"},
{"SEARCHVAL":"530106","CATEGORY":"Building",
    "X":"103.8907","Y":"1.3537"}]}
```

This is the pattern I tried to no avail:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\\"X:\\\"([0-9.]*)\\\",\\\"Y\\\":\"([0-9.]*)\\\"");  

Matcher m1 = p1.match(result);
if( m1.matches() ){
    print("match found");
}
```

I have also tried the following without any luck:

```
Pattern.compile("\"X:\"([0-9.]*)\",\"Y\":\"([0-9.]*)\"");
```

This should be easy, but yet I have been stuck here for the past 2 hours.

Comment: Should'nt it be parsed as json?

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions for this? The string you've listed is a simple JSON. you should use JSONObject/JSONArray to parse it.

Comment: If you want regex :- https://regex101.com/r/wE3dV6/1..in JAVA :- `\"X\":\"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\",\"Y\":\"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\"`

Comment: You forgot the `"` after `X` in your pattern. Change `\\\"X:` to `\\\"X\\\":`

Comment: I was wondering if there is a lot of overhead to use the JsonObject. (i will need to parse 100s of them).

Comment: FYI About first attempt: 1. You don't need to quote the `"` in the regex. 2. You're missing a `"` after the `X`and the `Y`. Second attempt: You forgot to escape the ``\``s.

Comment: unrelated to the question but still strange: why are all the numerical values represented as strings (i.e. in double quotes) rather than numbers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for others that are stuck with the same problem, the reason why .* is needed at the front/end is because i used the wrong method call.

according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()

> public boolean matches ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Tries to match the Pattern against the entire
>   region (or the entire input, if no region has been set).

It needs to match the **entire** region.

to do any match, i would need to use find() instead.

> public boolean find ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Moves to the next occurrence of the pattern in
>   the input. If a previous match was successful, the method continues
>   the search from the first character following that match in the input.
>   Otherwise it searches either from the region start (if one has been
>   set), or from position 0.

hope this is useful to others.

String.matches() provides more insights to matches() method http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html

> public boolean matches (String regularExpression)
>
> This method returns true only if the regular
>   expression matches the entire input string. A common mistake is to
>   assume that this method behaves like contains(CharSequence); if you
>   want to match anywhere within the input string, you need to add .* to
>   the beginning and end of your regular expression. See matches(String,
>   CharSequence).

Comment: You should add this as an edit to the question. You are stating why `.*` is needed at the start or end of the Regex, which does not directly answer the question of *What is wrong with the Pattern*. Since this is just a bit of extra information on the Regex you finally used, you should edit the question with this info. I have flagged it as *Not an Answer*

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx will work:

```
"X":"([0-9.]*)","Y":"([0-9.]*)"
```

The **`1st` Capture Group** contains the `X` value, and the **`2nd` Capture Group** contains the `Y` value

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kU7zV2/1)</kbd>

Which means your `Pattern.compile` should be:

```
Pattern.compile("\"X\":\"([0-9.]*)\",\"Y\":\"([0-9.]*)\"");
```

Note that you may need to add `.*` at the start of the RegEx for it to work.

Comment: strange... I need to add .* in the beginning for it to work. p = Pattern.compile(".*\"X\":\"([0-9.]*)\",\"Y\":\"([0-9.]*)\".*");

Comment: Maybe, yes. That will capture the data before the start of the `"X"`. It should have worked however since there was no `^` at the start of the RegEx. Oh well, problem solved!

Comment: @AngelKoh You should add that edit to the question. I added something along those lines to the answer, however it is against the rules to do what you tried (and so I had to reject your edit)

Answer (score 1):

If you want regex to parse it, then you can use:

```
"X":"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)","Y":"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE3dV6/1)**

You are missing a quote(`"`) after X in your regex. Though I recommend not to use your regex because it will also match `1.1.2.3`

In *JAVA*:

```
\"X\":\"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\",\"Y\":\"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\"
```

Comment: strange... I didn't downvote you. I would love to know why you are downvoted too.

Comment: @AngelKoh some people may not have liked the idea of doing it with regex instead of `JSON` parser